# Display probability for internal nodes in partykit conditional inference tree (classification tree)

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree, party

In the partykit package print(i.ctree) provides the probability of the outcome at terminal nodes (classification tree). However, I would like to know the probability of the outcome at internal nodes as well.

I'm able to estimate the probability at the internal nodes when I create a barplot for my ctree
plot(i.ctree, inner_panel = node_barplot). But what I would like is the exact probability at internal nodes. For example, in the diagram below I would like to know the probability of the outcome at nodes 2 and 5.

Any ideas?

Using an example from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/vignettes/ctree.pdf:

barplot of ctree:
[image: barplot of ctree]

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to extract the full data pertaining to a certain node and compute any quantity you are interested in. For the distribution of a classification tree one way is to coerce to the `simpleparty` class which stores the `distribution` in the `info` slots of each node.

Using the example from the vignette you mentioned, you can first fit the full `constparty` tree:

```
library("partykit")
data("GlaucomaM", package = "TH.data")
gtree <- ctree(Class ~ ., data = GlaucomaM)
```

And then coerce to `simpleparty`:

```
gtree <- as.simpleparty(gtree)
```

Then you can extract a list of distributions from each node, bind it into a table, and compute the proportions:

```
tab <- nodeapply(gtree, nodeids(gtree), function(node) node$info$distribution)
tab <- do.call(rbind, tab)
proportions(tab, 1)
##     glaucoma     normal
## 1 0.50000000 0.50000000
## 2 0.86206897 0.13793103
## 3 0.93670886 0.06329114
## 4 0.12500000 0.87500000
## 5 0.21100917 0.78899083
## 6 0.09230769 0.90769231
## 7 0.38636364 0.61363636
```

You can also adapt the panel function for the printing, re-using the functions used in `print.simpleparty`:

```
simpleprint <- function(node) formatinfo_node(node,
  FUN = partykit:::.make_formatinfo_simpleparty(gtree),
  default = "*", prefix = ": ")
print(gtree, inner_panel = simpleprint)
## Model formula:
## Class ~ ag + at + as + an + ai + eag + eat + eas + ean + eai + 
##     abrg + abrt + abrs + abrn + abri + hic + mhcg + mhct + mhcs + 
##     mhcn + mhci + phcg + phct + phcs + phcn + phci + hvc + vbsg + 
##     vbst + vbss + vbsn + vbsi + vasg + vast + vass + vasn + vasi + 
##     vbrg + vbrt + vbrs + vbrn + vbri + varg + vart + vars + varn + 
##     vari + mdg + mdt + mds + mdn + mdi + tmg + tmt + tms + tmn + 
##     tmi + mr + rnf + mdic + emd + mv
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] vari <= 0.059: glaucoma (n = 87, err = 13.8%)
## |   |   [3] vasg <= 0.066: glaucoma (n = 79, err = 6.3%)
## |   |   [4] vasg > 0.066: normal (n = 8, err = 12.5%)
## |   [5] vari > 0.059: normal (n = 109, err = 21.1%)
## |   |   [6] tms <= -0.066: normal (n = 65, err = 9.2%)
## |   |   [7] tms > -0.066: normal (n = 44, err = 38.6%)
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    3
## Number of terminal nodes: 4
```